# not to select if the column is having multiple values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The table `ORDER` below, i don't want to select the `customer_id` which is having `order_type`=636 and want to display all customer_ids that don't have the `order_type` '636' in SQL Query.

```
order_id         order_type       order_number     customer_id
----------       ----------       ------------    --------------
100              768              9900000011        2222
101              636              1021              2222
103              768              8800000022        3333
104              768              7700000033        4444
```

In the result i need only 3333 and 4444 values from customer_id column. If 636 is present in the order_type column then i have to omit the customer_id.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or DB2?

Comment: sql alone. sorry for the wrong label added.

Comment: You mean _MySQL alone_?

Comment: What do you need in the output - just the customer id's that satisfy your conditions (and then, perhaps, no duplicates - each customer id shown just once), or - more interesting, and more difficult, but not by much - the **full rows** for those customers, with all the order data from all columns (and all rows) for those customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
select customer_id
from `order`
where customer_id
NOT IN (select customer_id from order where order_type = 636))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the `customer_id` and take only those having no records with the condition you specify.

```
select customer_id
from "order"
group by customer_id
having sum(case when order_type = 636 then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants duplicates, so this is probably the most apt solution.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` might be one option (code you need starts at line #7):

```
SQL> with test (order_id, order_type, customer_id) as
  2    (select 100, 768, 2222 from dual union all
  3     select 101, 636, 2222 from dual union all
  4     select 103, 768, 3333 from dual union all
  5     select 104, 768, 4444 from dual
  6    )
  7  select customer_id
  8  from test t
  9  where not exists (select null from
 10                    test t1
 11                    where order_type = 636
 12                      and t1.customer_id = t.customer_id);

CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
       4444
       3333

SQL>
```